# Ocaml Pattern Matching Qualms

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm having a bit of a problem with regards to pattern matching in Ocaml.

Basically, I need to write a function named reversed that accepts a list and checks whether or not it is in reversed order.

So far:

```
let rec reversed (x:int list):bool =
   match x with
   | [] -> true
   | y::z::tl -> if y < z then false else reversed tl;
   | y::[] -> true;;
```

It works! (to my surprise actually :P) But there is a flaw I can see, that is if there is no more tl, it would not match. Testing this returns true:

```
  reversed [5;4;3;1;2];;
```

Which is perfectly understandable since there's no more tail and it simply matches to y::[]

How would I fix this?

PS: This is my first day with Ocaml. Sorry if the question is very easy :D

PPS: I am purposely only using Core. (no modules)

PPPS: I understand the case if I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, please do point it out.

Comment: In addition to the answers already given, let me nitpick that `if y < z then false else E` is just a convoluted way of saying `y >= z && E`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your function is here :

`| y::z::tl -> if y < z then false else reversed tl;`

Let's look at your list : [5;4;3;1;2]

It is decomposed this way :

`| 5::4::[3;1;2]`

And you compare 5 and 4, and then call reverted with [3;2;1]. Wich means that the **comparaison between 4 and 3 is not done !** (you can try with a list like [5;4;99;98;97], it is the unexpected result that you have).

What you should do is test on z, and then call reverted with the rest of the list. But if you try something like :

`| y::z::_ -> if y < z then false else reversed z;`

The compilers yells at you, because z is an int (and not an int list anymore). To solve this, you can "reconstruct" the list by adding z in front of tl :

`| y::z::tl -> if y < z then false else reversed (z::tl)`

Or name the list after y (which contains z) while still extracting z :

`| y::(z::_ as tl) -> if y < z then false else reversed tl`

As for your guess about the problem, I understand your logic but actually it does not work that way. 
[] can be "named" in your decomposition, just as if it was a regular node.

Look at this example, a (bad) function who tests if the end of the list is reached :

`let is_end l = match l with
| a -> false
| [] -> true;;`

If you try to put that in your interpreter, you should get the following message :
`Warning 11: this match case is unused.`

That's because [] is already caught in the first match case. You can try with `is_end []`, it returns false.

The correct way to handle this is how you did it in your code :

`let is_end l = match l with
| x::_ -> false
| [] -> true;;`

Answer (score 2):

Your program logic is wrong. You want to check if the list is reversed (decreasing?). But your program fails on input

```
[5;3;4;2;1]
```

telling you that it is reversed/decreasing. This is because you drop the 3 too early. Your middle clause should be:

```
   | y::z::tl -> if y < z then false else reversed (z::tl);
```

Comment: Holy crap didn't see that. Anyway, [5;4;3;1;2];; seem to work now too. Does y::z::tl catch that already or something?

Comment: @Secret sure, the pattern says: a list with at least 2 elements

Answer (score 1):

You should use `| y::z::tl -> if y < z then false else reversed (z::tl)`.

if y > z, you shouldn't drop z from the next round of list because z has not been compared to the next item yet.

Also you don't need **;** in that line.

the correct code is

```
let rec reversed = function
  | [] -> true
  | hd::[] -> true
  | hd1::hd2::tl ->
    if hd1 < hd2 then false
    else reversed (hd2::tl)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to write it using some other concepts like pattern guards and wild cards:

```
let rec reversed = function
  | [] | [_] -> true
  | hd1::hd2::_ when hd1 < hd2 -> false
  | _::tl -> reversed tl;;
```

This way there is one case for true, one for false, and one recursive.

Comment: Lol I'm embarrassed to say I had no idea 'when' existed, thanks. This is pretty clean